# SQL Server SSAS Calculated Measure with DateDiff

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, mdx, datediff

I'm trying to create a calculated member in SSAS using the datediff function, but can't seem to get it working at all.

The requirement is as follows,

datediff(day, XDate where Type = 2 AND Status IN (1,2,3), XDate where Type = 3)

I'm not sure on how to translate that to the proper MDX for a calculated measure in SSAS.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Somthing is not right here. You should add that `datediff` on your Data source view, and then use it on a measure

Comment: @Lamak
I'm not completely sure how I would go about that either. Let's say this is my DSV,

select Key1, Key2, Key3, TypeKey, TypeValue
from Fact_view

Comment: I think that I misunderstood your question. You want to calculate `DATEDIFF` between rows from the same column?. If so, It can't be on the DSV, and you'll need some complicated MDX to help you with that

Comment: @Lamak Not really, given the conditions of the DATEDIFF parameters, parameter 1 where Type = 2 and parameter 2 where status IN (1,2,3) and Type =3. This means they should be on different rows given the different types (2 and 3).

Comment: Yes, but you are still trying to use `DATEDIFF` on 2 different values of the same column, that, as it is, can't be done on the DSV.

Comment: @Lamak Yes you are correct then. Same column, but different value in different rows. Do you have any suggestions for the MDX?

Comment: I don't think it can be done correctly. If I have multiple rows, how could it know wich ones needs to be evaluated on your function, and then you need to aggregat them. Its different than just `SUM` something, because the order of the rows will affect the result. You need to clarify what you really want with some examples and data.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the structure of your cube? Is XDate a dimension? Is Type a dimension? Is Status a dimension?

Comment: @Stacia XDate is an attribute within a dimension, so [XDateS].[XDate].[xDate] ,and Status and Type are also attributes in another dimension

Comment: I have an idea about this, but another question is how are you using the calculated member in a query? Basically, the arguments you use in the DateDiff function must be one and only one date for the beginning date and the end date. Is it true that there is only one date for which the specified conditions is true? Does it change based on something you display in the result set on rows or columns? You need to disclose more of what you're trying to do in order to get help on the MDX in this case.

Comment: @Stacia Yes, there is only 1 date for the beginning date and end date, one date for that record. Is it possible to code if there's more than one possible date? I'm basically trying to find the amount of time between two dates for a given status/type change. On a given date, the status is 5. The status and type may change later, and I want to measure that time in days.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample query showing a calculated measure called DateDiff. I prefer to break down complex calculations into smaller parts for easier troubleshooting. You can combine if you like. I've invented some dimensions and measures here but hopefully you can see how this works and adapt accordingly. Basically, I'm getting a set that combines a record with specific status codes (or type codes) and getting all the related dates, but only those that have a fact table row for a measure called Status Count (arbitrary - any measure in fact table will do). Then I pick off the last one - assuming all is in date order which it should be if your dimension sort is correct, and pick out the date with extract - and then because it's a set - reduce it to a member with Item(0).Item(0). Then get its name for use in the DateDiff function. I've included some logic to make sure the current record is not the All member and that the first date is not empty.

```
    with 
    member [Measures].[First Date] as
      iif(Record.Record.CurrentMember Is [Record].[Record].[All],
      null,
Extract(
Tail(
NonEmpty(
    (Record.Record.CurrentMember, 
    {[Status Code].[Status].&[1],[Status Code].[Status].&[2],[Status Code].[Status].&[2]},
    [Date].[Date].[Date].Members),
    [Measures].[Status Count]), 1), [Date].[Date])
).Item(0).Item(0).Name

member measures.[Second Date] as

iif(Record.Record.CurrentMember Is [Record].[Record].[All],
null,

Extract(
Tail(
NonEmpty(
    (Record.Record.CurrentMember, 
    [Type].[Type].&[3],
    [Date].[Date].[Date].Members),
    [Measures].[Status Count]), 1), [Date].[Date])
).Item(0).Item(0).Name

member measures.[DateDiff] as 

iif(IsEmpty([Measures].[First Date]), null, 
datediff("d", [Measures].[First Date], [Measures].[Second Date]))

select
{[Measures].[Status Count], 
[Measures].[First Date], 
[Measures].[Second Date], 
[Measures].[DateDiff]}
on columns,
[Record].members on rows
from [status]
```

Comment: Okay if I'm creating a new calculated member from this then I would just use everything before the select statement?
Thank you

Comment: I would suggest creating 3 calculated measures. You can rename of course but here I have First Date, Second Date, and Date Diff. When you create each one, use the code between AS and the next MEMBER (or SELECT in the last case for DateDiff).

Comment: Stacia, what exactly does "Record.Record.CurrentMember" represent?

Comment: It's my best guess at what you were describing in your question: "only 1 date for the beginning date and end date, one date for that record". There has to be something in that calculation besides dates that I am generically referring to as record. It's some other dimension in your fact table. So let's use AdventureWorks as an example - it could be Product. So you would refer to Product.Product.CurrentMember to find the date diff for the status change by product.